# Two question marks together mean in C# Accepts only null not Blank Why?

Tags: c#

As i am using following Scenario in my project

```
String Test = String.Empty;
String Test1 = null;
String Test2 = "b";
Test = Test1 ?? Test2;
```

In this Scenario  Test Contains the value "b"

But

```
String Test = String.Empty;
String Test1 = String.Empty;
String Test2 = "b";
Test = Test1 ?? Test2;
```

This Scenario Test conatins value ""

Why? Is "Test = Test1 ?? Test2;" this statement works only null values?

Answer (score 11):

Correct.. which is why it is called the [null coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx).

An empty string is not null.. therefore it doesn't meet the requirements of the operator.

Answer (score 10):

It's because the string isn't null :-). It's just empty - very different.

For instance, with an empty string, you can call methods on the string, like so:

```
var s = "";
Debug.WriteLine(s.Length);
```

You can't do that with a string variable that's null:

```
string s = null;
Debug.WriteLine(s.Length); // <- Will throw a null reference exception
```

To get the results you want, you need to do this:

```
Test = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Test1) ? Test2 : Test1;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the conditional operator if you need to check for both nulls and empty / whitespace only, e.g.

```
Test = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Test1)
 ? Test2
 : Test1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got all the answers you need, but I wanted to just expand a little on the null coalescing operator. It is just short-hand, some syntactic sugar, to save some code (in the same way that the `? :` conditional operator is short-hand.

`Test1 ?? Test2;`

is just a short-hand way of writing

`if (Test1 == null)
{
    Test1 = Test2
}`

... and as others have said, `null != string.Empty`. If you want to test for `string.Empty` then you can't use this particular short-hand. You'll have to write it out the long-hand way, or use the `? :` short-cut.